# How to create a horizontally scrollable container with varied child heights?

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I am facing a challenging CSS layout issue and need help. My goal is to have a header in a container that follows the horizontal scroll at all times, but only follows the vertical scroll when vertical scrolling is present.

The container will have multiple documents with varying heights. A key requirement is that the container should not expand to the height of the tallest document, which adds complexity to the task.

[Initial view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCSMS.png)

[After scrolling to left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd14s.png)

Specific Requirements:

- The header should always follow horizontal scrolling.
- The header should follow vertical scrolling only when vertical scroll is present in the container.
- The container should maintain its size and not expand to the height of the tallest contained element.
- Ensure a smooth scrolling experience.
- Achieve mobile/desktop, cross-browser, cross-platform compatibility.

Questions:

- Is there a way to achieve this with CSS, possibly with advanced properties or techniques?
- If a JavaScript solution is necessary, how can I optimize it for smooth scrolling and broad compatibility?

Any guidance or advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

Here's what I've explored so far:

- I've looked into the CSS contain property to isolate a subsection of the DOM, but it doesn't quite solve the issue.
- I tried a JavaScript-based solution, but it resulted in a lack of smoothness and cross-browser compatibility issues (scroll event / Intersection Observer).

Based setup => https://codepen.io/samuelclo/pen/poYorbv?editors=1100

```js
const getScrollbarWidth = () => {
  // Creating invisible container
  const outer = document.createElement("div");
  outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
  outer.style.overflow = "scroll"; // forcing scrollbar to appear
  // @ts-expect-error needed for WinJS apps
  outer.style.msOverflowStyle = "scrollbar";
  document.body.appendChild(outer);

  // Creating inner element and placing it in the container
  const inner = document.createElement("div");
  outer.appendChild(inner);

  // Calculating difference between container's full width and the child width
  const scrollbarWidth = outer.offsetWidth - inner.offsetWidth;

  // Removing temporary elements from the DOM
  outer.parentNode?.removeChild(outer);

  return scrollbarWidth;
};

document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
  "--scrollbar-width-js",
  getScrollbarWidth() + "px"
);
```

```css
:root {
  --common-width: 300px;
  --scrollbar-width: var(--scrollbar-width-js, 12px)
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}

.card {
  width: var(--common-width);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02), 0 0 0 1px rgba(27, 31, 35, 0.15);
}

header {
  top: 0;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  /* Use to define a height because if all child is exclude from the DOM there is no height min-height: 100vh; */
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.l-include-gutter {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  /* Pretty recent */
  /* https://caniuse.com/?search=contain */
  contain: size;

  /* Add scroll bar width */
  scrollbar-gutter: stable;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /* Because child has a more than 100% width */
  overflow-x: clip;
}

.l-article {
  width: calc(100% + var(--scrollbar-width));
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

/* For safari */
/* https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_scrollbar-gutter */
@supports not (scrollbar-gutter: stable) {
  .l-article {
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="card">
  <h2>
    Exploring Transformation: Artificial Intelligence and Climate Change
  </h2>
  <p>
    Delve into two distinct yet interconnected realms of human innovation
    and global concern. First, journey through the evolution of Artificial
    Intelligence (AI) as it progresses from its mid-20th-century inception
    to the transformative technology it is today. Discover how AI has
    revolutionized industries, healthcare, and decision-making, while also
    posing challenges like job displacement and bias.
  </p>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="l-include-gutter">
    <div class="l-article">
      <button>Click on me !</button>
      <article class="card">
        <h3>Climate change</h3>
        <p>
          Climate change is one of the most pressing issues facing humanity
          today. It refers to long-term changes in global temperature and
          weather patterns, primarily driven by human activities such as the
          burning of fossil fuels, deforestation, and industrial processes.
        </p>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="l-include-gutter">
    <div class="l-article">
      <button>Click on me !</button>
      <article class="card">
        <h3>The Evolution of Artificial Intelligence</h3>
        <p>
          Artificial Intelligence (AI) has come a long way since its
          inception in the mid-20th century. The term "artificial
          intelligence" was first coined by John McCarthy in 1956 during a
          Dartmouth College workshop. Early AI research focused on symbolic
          reasoning and rule-based systems, but progress was slow due to
          limited computing power.
        </p>

        <p>
          In the 21st century, AI entered a new era, thanks to advancements
          in machine learning and neural networks. Deep learning, a subset
          of machine learning, made it possible for computers to process
          vast amounts of data and perform complex tasks. This breakthrough
          paved the way for the development of AI systems that could
          understand natural language, recognize images, and even beat human
          champions in games like chess and Go.
        </p>

        <h3>Applications of AI Across Industries</h3>
        <p>
          AI has revolutionized healthcare by improving diagnosis,
          treatment, and patient care. Machine learning algorithms can
          analyze medical images, such as X-rays and MRI scans, to detect
          abnormalities and assist radiologists in making accurate
          diagnoses. Additionally, AI-driven chatbots and virtual nurses are
          enhancing patient engagement and monitoring.
        </p>

        <p>
          In the financial industry, AI is used for algorithmic trading,
          fraud detection, credit risk assessment, and customer service.
          AI-powered robo-advisors provide personalized investment
          recommendations, while natural language processing enables
          sentiment analysis of news and social media for trading decisions.
        </p>

        <p>
          AI is transforming education through personalized learning
          platforms that adapt to students' needs and abilities. Intelligent
          tutoring systems provide instant feedback and tailored exercises,
          enhancing student performance. Furthermore, AI-driven analytics
          help educators identify at-risk students and implement timely
          interventions.
        </p>

        <p>
          Automation and robotics have long been associated with
          manufacturing, but AI is taking these technologies to the next
          level. AI-driven robots can perform complex tasks with precision,
          reducing errors and increasing efficiency. Predictive maintenance
          powered by AI minimizes equipment downtime, saving companies
          millions.
        </p>

        <p>
          The transportation sector is experiencing a seismic shift with
          AI-driven autonomous vehicles. Companies like Tesla and Waymo are
          developing self-driving cars that promise safer and more efficient
          transportation. AI also optimizes traffic management, reducing
          congestion and emissions.
        </p>

        <p>
          AI has made its mark in the entertainment industry through content
          recommendation systems like Netflix's recommendation algorithm.
          Additionally, AI-generated art and music are gaining recognition
          in the creative world, blurring the lines between human and
          machine creativity.
        </p>

        <h3>Benefits of AI</h3>
        <p>AI offers numerous benefits, including:</p>
        <ul>
          <li>
            Efficiency and Productivity: AI automates routine tasks, freeing
            up human workers to focus on more creative and strategic
            endeavors. This increases productivity and reduces the risk of
            human error.
          </li>
          <li>
            Improved Decision-Making: AI systems can analyze vast datasets
            and provide insights that humans might overlook. This helps
            businesses make data-driven decisions and stay competitive.
          </li>
          <li>
            Enhanced Healthcare: AI assists medical professionals in
            diagnosing diseases, predicting outbreaks, and developing
            personalized treatment plans, ultimately improving patient
            outcomes.
          </li>
          <li>
            Safety and Security: AI is used in cybersecurity to detect and
            prevent cyberattacks. It also enhances physical security through
            facial recognition and surveillance systems.
          </li>
        </ul>

        <h3>Challenges and Concerns</h3>
        <p>
          Despite its advantages, AI also presents challenges and concerns:
        </p>
        <ul>
          <li>
            Job Displacement: One of the most significant concerns
            surrounding AI is the potential for job displacement. As AI
            systems automate tasks, some traditional jobs may become
            obsolete, requiring a shift in workforce skills and retraining.
          </li>
          <li>
            Bias and Fairness: AI algorithms can inherit biases present in
            the data they are trained on, leading to discriminatory
            outcomes. Ensuring fairness and transparency in AI systems is a
            critical challenge.
          </li>
          <li>
            Privacy: AI systems often require access to vast amounts of
            personal data. Protecting individuals' privacy while harnessing
            the power of AI is an ongoing concern.
          </li>
        </ul>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: sticky`. It will works perfectly how you expect.

```
<header id="main-header"></header>
```

```
#main-header {
  position: sticky;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't understand how you would apply this based on the provided code. Do you think you could provide some example code or explain your method further?

Comment: @samuelClo For sure, take a look at this [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/cz05hvst/), I have added to your code.

Comment: Thank you for your example, but I believe my expectation wasn't clear. In your demonstration, the header is positioned behind all the content, and my solution doesn't address this. My expectation is to have a standard vertical scroll on the body displaying my two articles without showing a scrollbar when it's not necessary. Does that make sense?